# How to select a maximum value row in 2 mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as follows:

Table: Visitor

```
---------------------
|     Code    |Contr|
|-------------------|
|225919528553 | 1003|
|-------------------|
|130324727131 | 1004|
|-------------------|
|353952972425 | 1010|
|-------------------|
|997498622785 | 1014|
|-------------------|
|
|
|
```

Table: Products

```
-----------------------------
|    Code     | Name| Color |
|----------------------------
|225919528553 | Pen | Balck |
|----------------------------
|130324727131 | Book| White |
|----------------------------
|353952972425 | Fan | Black |
|----------------------------
|997498622785 | DVD |  Red  |
|----------------------------
|
|
|
```

.

I want to more value  of the `"Contr"` column following is displayed:

```
|    Code     | Name| Color | Contr |
|------------------------------------
|997498622785 | DVD |  Red  | 1014  |
|------------------------------------
|353952972425 | Fan | Black | 1010  |
|------------------------------------
|130324727131 | Book| White | 1004  |
|------------------------------------
|225919528553 | Pen | Balck | 1003  |
|------------------------------------
|
|
```

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f6f23a85-d8b8-4900-b72a-8ccb7b8abf25/view-source

Comment: Just use `JOIN` command

Comment: `join` both the tables

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
SELECT p.*, v.Contr
FROM Visitor AS v
JOIN Products AS p ON p.Code = v.Code
```

Comment: I get this error:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...

Answer (score 1):

I would find more value in the table!?

Answer (score 0):

```
select v.Code,
p.Name,
p.Color,
p.Contr 
from 
Visitor as v,
Products p 
where 
v.code=p.code order by contr
```